# Ruby on Rails Moving from CSV to FasterCSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, fastercsv

I currently have the following code to parse a csv file using the standard csv library

```
@parsed_file=CSV::Reader.parse(params[:dump][:file])
@parsed_file.each  do |row|
#some code
end
```

I want to move this to faster csv for the increased speed.  Does anyone know the equivalent of the above for FasterCSV?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CSV::Reader.parse(File.open('file.csv')){|row| puts row} 
or
CSV::Reader.parse("some, content\nanother, content"){|row| puts row}
```

and

```
FasterCSV.parse(File.open('file.csv')){|row| puts row}
or
FasterCSV.parse("some, content\nanother, content"){|row| puts row}
```

are equivalent.

But

```
FasterCSV.read('filename')
```

takes filename as parameter and reads and parse data from the file however you are dumping the file content as you  are passing data in the parameter

```
@parsed_file = FasterCSV.parse(params[:dump][:file])
@parsed_file.each do |row| 
  puts row
  # and do some operations
end
```

should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

To do it with a file path (as you appear to be):

```
FasterCSV.read(params[:dump][:file])
```

You can check the [FasterCSV docs](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) for other ways to do it (e.g., process each row as it's parsed, or read from a string instead of a file).